# How many spells can I learn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a maximum limit to the number of spells that I can learn at any one time? I haven't seen a "un-lean spell" button anywhere, but it would be good to know in case I am taking up room with low level utility spells.

Comment: LEARN ALL THE SPELLS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can learn as many spells as you can read spell books. The spells you have already learned will remain in your spell list. The only disadvantage of having too many spells is scrolling through them.

Answer (score -2):

There *is* a limit. I've bought over 150 spell books via a mod and I hit the limit, though I don't know the exact number. The limit is per category, e.g. destruction can be 150 and same with alt.

Comment: And what happens when you hit the limit?